# How do I create a custom linux image for flash?

Tags: google-coral

We integrated some hardware including Intel realsense into the Coral dev board.

For hardware integration, the SDK provided by the hardware manufacturer was built and installed.

Since it takes a lot of time to build and install the SDK, I want to use a different devboard by making an image of Linux with the SDK installed.

Ask for help on what to do

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a Live ISO containing some custom programs (the SDK), no?

If yes, there are some tools available in the web for this purpose:

1. If you are using Ubuntu Linux, there is a [guide](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/image-building)
2. A more custom way will be [Linux Live](https://www.linux-live.org/)
3. For more tools take a look at [this article](https://www.linuxadictos.com/en/create-linux-distribution.html)

I hope that it helped,

Juanjo Asensio García